# How can I provide an autocomplete filter for tags in a Search API view?

Tags: 8, search

I'm working to create a Search API view. I have an exposed filter that's a fulltext search filter. I'd like to expose another filter that works similar to the exposed entity reference, which allows users to reference multiple tags, separated by commas; the field will then autocomplete the entered value.

Is there a way to achieve this using the Search API Views and the Search API Autocomplete modules?  As far as I can see, there isn't a way to autocomplete multiple words/phrases, instead of just the first word/phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the datasource (entity reference) as a exposed filter. 
[image]

Check the "allow multiple selections".

[image]

Now, the user can add comma seperated tags (with autocompletion):
[image]

Used search api 8.x-1.13 on drupal 8.6.16

Answer (score 1):

I would enable the Facet API module first of all, which will give you the facet interaction with Search API.

I would then point you towards a good, simple tutorial at https://medium.com/@swappyp20/creating-a-faceted-search-view-in-drupal-8-using-the-search-api-modules-2b2604ad37f4

Hopefully you should be able to sort it out from there.

Comment: Indeed. Facets is the way to go here.

Comment: Facets would be good if I had 50 or 100 tags, but there are thousands of tags.  The autocomplete functionality is really important.  There is the "facets autocomplete" module but it's a sandbox module and doesn't seem to work right.

Answer (score 1):

In **Filter criteria** you need to Add the tag (Taxonomy) fields to extract right values from views. Also remember to select **expose this filter to visitors** and **selection type - Autocomplete and check Allow Multiple Selections**. You can see attached screenshots below.

I hope these will help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is good info about how to add contextual filters to views, but ultimately doesn't answer the question which was how to add autocomplete exposed filters to search_api views.

Comment: @Matt I want you to recover your vote!, I edited the answer, it is not difficult to select autocomplete and expose filter to visitors to allow to change it